# Django ModelForm make field from other fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have these models

```
class Color(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Tshirt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
```

And I have this form

```
class TshirtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    color_code = forms.CharField(min_length=7, max_length=7)
    class Meta:
        model = Tshirt
        fields = ('name',)
```

How can I get the Color object from the color_code field and save that as the color of the new tshirt when the modelform is saved?

Comment: Can you not just have it as a dropdown choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your users to choose a color just extend the fields

```
class TshirtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tshirt
        fields = ('name', 'color')
```

This will give you a select field in your form. Just make sure you add some colors for your users to choose from.

But if you want your users to "create" new colors, you should use two forms, one for color and the other one for the Tshirt. It's way simpler, than trying to do all in one form.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, update your form like this:

```
class TshirtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    color_code = forms.CharInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Tshirt
        fields = ('name', 'color')
        widget = {'color': forms.HiddenInput(required=False)}

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If users are typing the code, better do some validation
        try:
            color = Color.objects.get(
                code=self.cleaned_data.get('color_code')
            )
        except (ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Something went wrong with your code!')
        else:
            # Update the actual field
            self.cleaned_data['color'] = color.id
```

Comment: I want the users to choose a color but I don't want the color to be in a select field I want the color to be gotten from the code that they enter.

Comment: Yep, missed that. Added and else statement: if an exception is caught, that line won't run.

Comment: I'm curious, are you using a color picker which returns a color hex?

Comment: Yes. Also, I edited your code to make it work. There were just 2 small changes: form widgets don't have a "required" argument so I had to explicitly set that on the color form field, and the cleaned_data['color'] needs to be a color instance and not the color id.